# Error while outputting sessions in other page

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I created a login page in PHP with session. everything is going well. but when i try to output the session in other page. it giving me NOTICE

> Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\COIN Website\test5.php on line 81
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\COIN Website\test5.php on line 82
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\COIN Website\test5.php on line 84

I don't know whats wrong. Actually, I am new to PHP.

here is the login page

```
<?php
session_start();

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

           $servername = "localhost";
           $username = "root";
           $password = "";
           $db_name = "coins";

         $con = mysqli_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password","$db_name");

        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $eth = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eth']);
        if (empty($email) || empty($eth)) {
           header("Location: home.php?Login=Empty_fields");
          exit();
        } else{
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' ";
          $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
          $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

          if ($resultCheck < 1) {
             header("Location: home.php?Login=user_does_not_exist");
          exit();
          }

        else {
           $check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE eth='$eth'");
             if (mysqli_num_rows($check) >= 1) {
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
             $_SESSION['eth'] = $row['eth'];
      header("Location: pow.php?Login=Success");
             } else {
       header("Location: home.php?Login=invaild_email_or_eth address");
                           
          }
        }
         }
             }else {
             header("Location: home.php?Login=Error");
                   exit();
           }
              ?>
```

and the other page code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$servername = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
     $password = "";
    $dbname = "coins";

      // Create connection
         $conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $dbname);
         // Check connection
              if ($conn->connect_error) {
           die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 

     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        echo $email;
         $sql = "INSERT INTO profile (email, action_points)
         VALUES ('$email' , '0.003')";



    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "success";
         } else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
     }

       $conn->close();
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Are these code examples from the aforementioned `test5.php`? Please indicate which code corresponds to the line numbers referenced in the errors.

Comment: you should have session_start(); on each page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this. you are doing wrong with get session variable value.

```
 <?php session_start();

 // check session  

 if(isset($_SESSION['email']))

 {

 $email = $_SESSION['email'];

 // Now you can do your stuff

 }

 else 

 {

 echo "session not set for email";

 die;

}
```